# AngularJS OrderBy not updating after updating scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a simple app that displays a list in a view, which is generated by a Web API service call.

I order the results by true/false for an "isActive" param.

```
  <tr ng-repeat="row in orgs | filter:search | orderBy:['-IsActive','NetworkOrgFullName']">
```

I have a POST method I call when a user checks/unchecks the "isActive" checkbox for an item.

In my controller:

```
$scope.statusUpdate = function (row) {
    if (row.IsActive == true) {
        row.IsActive = false;
    } else {
        row.isActive = true;
    }
    orgPushFactory.update(row);
}
```

Everything works, but the view does not update to re-sort the results.

Any ideas how I can re-invoke the orderBy each time someone makes a change?

Comment: can you share your code in Jsfiddle to replicate your problem

Comment: Hi Thinker, I added a snippet from my controller. I have a web api service I'm calling using $resource, which is not accessible publicly, so I can't really recreate it in JsFiddle. However, it should be pretty easy to see what's going on. I'm using the "orderBy" filter in the view. When someone checks/unchecks a checkbox on a particular record it calls the $scope.statusUpdate method and updates the db. However, it does not update the view order.

Comment: Show the code where `statusUpdate()` is being called

Answer (score 0):

You may wrap your function call in scope.apply:

```
$scope.$apply($scope.statusUpdate);
```

Comment: Thanks, Keito. Unfortunately I get an rootScope error saying there is an ingest in progress. I'm going to keep looking for a solution, but appreciate your input.